# How can I set a timeout for a Ballerina HTTP client?

Tags: http, https, ballerina, ballerina-http

I have a Ballerina service that internally calls another service using an HTTP client. Due to a delay in the service response, I need to increase the client timeout. I'm currently encountering the following error due to the client timeout.

`error: Idle timeout triggered before initiating inbound response`

How can I increase the timeout for a Ballerina HTTP client?

Answer (score 1):

The timeout field in [HTTP client configurations](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#ClientConfiguration) is used to gracefully handle response delays that could occur due to network problems or the back-end. The client timeout can be configured in the timeout field of the client configuration in seconds.

```
http:Client httpClient = new ("localhost:9090", {timeout: 10});
```

The default timeout is 30 seconds. For more details, refer to the Ballerina [HTTP client timeout example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-timeout/).